# Bootstrap Reordering 3x2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap version 3 to create a responsive website.

I would like this layout on md devices and wider.

[image: layout for md and above, 2 rows 3 columns]

and this layout on viewports less than md.

[image: layout for below md, 6 rows 1 column]

Here's my code for the over-md view. I'm using jade, please ask for html if you need it.

```
.container
.row
  .col-md-4
    |Image 1
  .col-md-4
    |Image 2
  .col-md-4
    |Image 3
.row
  .col-md-4
    |Text 1
  .col-md-4
    |Text 2
  .col-md-4
    |Text 3
```

The following screenshots are the resulting browser views at over-md and under-md widths:

Wide viewport (over md)
[image: Browser view wide]

Thin viewport (under-md)

[image: Browser view thin]

My question is how to I change the order of the rows in the thin view to the order I need?

EDIT:
I changed my code. Organised rows to match smaller viewport requirement and attempted to use .col-md-push/pull to reorganise grid elements for wider viewports (md and over).

```
.container
.row
  .col-md-4
    |Image 1
  .col-md-4.col-md-push-8
    |Text 1
  .col-md-4.col-md-pull-4
    |Image 2
  .col-md-4.col-md-pull-4
    |Text 2
  .col-md-4
    |Image 3
  .col-md-4
    |Text 3
```

This code produced the following - nearly there, but the elements don't wrap between the rows, but were pushed outside the 12-columns container. I was hoping they would wrap as they seem to do here http://www.bootply.com/121418 
[image: Push Pull on md viewport]

Comment: Have a look here at the push/pull options: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nested grid will solve this. You basically create another row within a column, and then add columns within. See below. Read nesting columns from the bootstrap site:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">Image 1</div>
       <div class="col-md-12">Text 1</div>
     </div><!-- end inner row-->
    </div><!-- end col-sm-12 col-md-4-->
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">Image 2</div>
       <div class="col-md-12">Text 2</div>
     </div><!-- end inner row-->
    </div><!-- end col-sm-12 col-md-4-->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">Image 3</div>
       <div class="col-md-12">Text 3</div>
     </div><!-- end inner row-->
    </div><!-- end col-sm-12 col-md-4-->
</div><!-- end outer row-->
```

Comment: That did the trick thank you. It hurts my head to think how it works but it does.

Comment: Glad it helped! I know it can get a little crazy, just remember that when you nest you need to start a new row.

Answer (score 0):

use .col-xs class with col-md 
 this will solve your issue 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/
read out the grid options there .

Comment: I'm not sure how using .col-xs explicitly will solve the ordering problem. I think that when the viewport is under md width it switches to .col-xs-12. I checked this out by adding .col-xs-6 to my .col-md-4 which confirmed this assumption. What I couldn't do is change the order of the <sm grid elements. Push/pull/offset didn't allow me to change the order of elements either.

Comment: if you give col-xs with col-md it will automatically change according to the size .col-xs support < 768 size give  your column size according to window size so when browser windows come smaller then 768 col-xs class will automatically implemented on this same goes for co-sm it implemented on > 768 and goes on.

Comment: this is general example code to give an idea <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-12">Image 1</div>
       <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">Text 1</div>
     </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">Image 2</div>
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12  col-md-12">Text 2</div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>